# vectorization of scipy.linalg.solve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I have many of small, say 5 x 5, matrices, `A = numpy.random.rand(5, 5, 7, 77)` with one right-hand side `y = numpy.random.rand(5)`. I'd like to solve all 7 x 77 problems `A_{ij} x = b`, such that the result `x` has shape `5, 7, 77`. I can simply loop over them,

```py
from scipy.linalg import solve
import numpy

A = numpy.random.rand(5, 5, 7, 77)
b = numpy.random.rand(5)

x = []
for i in range(A.shape[2]):
    x.append([])
    for j in range(A.shape[3]):
        x[-1].append(solve(A[:, :, i, j], b))

x = numpy.array(x)
x = numpy.moveaxis(x, -1, 0)

print(x.shape)
```

but this is slow. It feels that it should be possible to vectorize by treating `A` not as a 5 x 5 x 7 x 77 tensor or floats, but as a 5 x 5 matrix of 7 x 77 float arrays, and perform all operations in `solve` on those arrays. Any hints?

(I come across these kind of problems rather often, so if there's a library handling them, I'd also be glad to hear about it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with [`np.linalg.solve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) if you reorder the dimensions first.

```py
import numpy as np

# Make random problem
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(5, 5, 7, 77)
b = np.random.rand(5)
# Put additional axes at the end
at = np.moveaxis(a, (0, 1), (2, 3))
# Solve
xt = np.linalg.solve(at, b[np.newaxis, np.newaxis])
# Put axes back in place
x = np.moveaxis(xt, 2, 0)
print(x.shape)
# (5, 7, 77)
# Test some result
print(np.allclose(a[:, :, 4, 36] @ x[:, 4, 36], b))
# True
```